# WPF DataGrid custom column (not templateColumn)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Does anyone have a proper functional example of how to create a custom datagrid column? I want to make one with more bindable properties (ie value, decimalCount, unit). I do NOT want to use the template column.

My main problem is that I am unable to figure out how to get the proper datacontext in my control. I inherit the DataGrid's context, and am unable to get down to the individual item for each row.

I added dependency properties for the control, but as they try bind to properties on the parent collection they just end up being null.

ok, here's one of my would-be attempts:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Project.Common.Converters;

namespace Project.Areas.Schedule
{
    public class ColumnTest2 : DataGridColumn
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Unit", typeof(string), typeof(ColumnTest), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public string Unit
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(UnitProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UnitProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DecimalCountProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DecimalCount", typeof(int), typeof(ColumnTest), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

        public int DecimalCount
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(DecimalCountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DecimalCountProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty QuantityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Quantity", typeof(decimal), typeof(ColumnTest), new PropertyMetadata(default(decimal)));

        public decimal Quantity
        {
            get { return (decimal)GetValue(QuantityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(QuantityProperty, value); }
        }


        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            if (Quantity == null || DecimalCount == null || Unit == null)
                return null;


            TextBlock cellElement = new TextBlock();
            var valueBinding = new MultiBinding
            {
                Converter = new QuantityToStringMultiValueConverter(),
                Bindings =
                {
                        new Binding{Source = dataItem, Path=Quantity.Path},
                        new Binding{Source = dataItem, Path=DecimalCount.Path},
                        new Binding{Source = dataItem, Path=Unit.Path},
                }
            };
            cellElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, valueBinding);

            return cellElement;
        }

        protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ScheduleLines}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" Header="Normal Column"/>
                <schedule:ColumnTest2 Quantity="{Binding DeliveredQuantity}" DecimalCount="{Binding Decimals}" Unit="{Binding Unit}" Header="Custom Column"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

If you try this in visual studio you will see that on the "normal" columns intellisense knows we're looking at items on the item level, while on our newly attempt Custom Column intellisense suggests items on the parent level (and this is also true runtime - so it doesnt find the properties).

PS: The converter class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/hbrxVRw6

Comment: Please show some code, what have you already done?

Comment: I have tried various approaches, but honestly I have nothing to show so far that I know is right

Comment: Post your data model code at least. And maybe a picture of what you are trying to achieve. It is hard to help if we have to guess.

Comment: Will do. Posted

Comment: I also added some xaml code for how I'd like to use it.

Comment: Forget about bindings for a while, but how the custom column is supposed to display the data without a template?

Comment: The GenerateElement method returns a TextBlock that displays the data.

Comment: I have updated the code to something that is now actually functioning runtime, but it's an ugly hack and I don't like it. Also it doesn't work in the designer without setting a d:DataContext manually, which is not the route I want to go (this does work for proper columns!)

Comment: I would try to extend `DataGridBoundColumn`.

Comment: I tried that jstreet. Same there :\